# Reading Error in Mail JAVA

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am reading email from gmail.com. i have read some of the mail successfully but after a while i got this,

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: 
 javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart cannot be cast to java.lang.String
 at emailIngestion.EmailIngestion.check(EmailIngestion.java:66)
 at emailIngestion.EmailIngestion.main(EmailIngestion.java:106).
```

Actually my requirement is to store content into a variable and then store it in arraylist and then again write it to a file... i have implemented it using this code so if any better ideas are there please share me.

```
public class EmailIngestion {   
static ArrayList<EmailModel> contentList=new ArrayList<EmailModel>();
static ArrayList<EmailModel> metaDataList= new ArrayList<EmailModel>();
public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user,
        String password) throws IOException 
{
    FileWriter fw= new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\murtaza_metadata.csv",true);
    FileWriter fw1= new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\murtaza_content.txt",true);
    try {
        //create properties field
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
        properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
        properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
        Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
        Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");
        store.connect(host, user, password);
        Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
        int emailNumber;
        String mailContent = null,from = null,to = null,mailContentType = null,subject = null;
        Date recievedDate= new Date(); 
        System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);
        for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
            Message message = messages[i];
            System.out.println("Subject is"+message.getSubject());
            subject = message.getSubject();
            from =  message.getFrom()[0].toString();
            mailContentType=message.getContentType();
            recievedDate=message.getSentDate();
            to=InternetAddress.toString(message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
            emailNumber=message.getMessageNumber();
            metaDataList.add(new EmailModel(from, to, subject, mailContentType, recievedDate,emailNumber));
            fw.write(emailNumber+"\001"+from+"\001"+subject+"\001"+recievedDate+mailContentType+"\001"+" \n");
            fw.flush();
            if(message.isMimeType("multipart/*")){
                Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent(); 
                for (int x = 0; x < multipart.getCount(); x++) {
                    BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(x);
                        mailContent=(String) bodyPart.getContent();
                        System.out.println(mailContent);
                    }
                }
            else{
                mailContent=(String) message.getContent();
                System.out.println(message.getContent());
            }
            contentList.add(new EmailModel(mailContent, emailNumber));
            fw1.write(emailNumber+","+mailContent+"\n");
        }
        emailFolder.close(false);
        store.close();

    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String host = "pop.gmail.com";// change accordingly
    String mailStoreType = "pop3";
    String username = "abcd@gmail.com";// change accordingly
    String password = "******";// change accordingly
    check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);

}
```

}

Thanks in advance

Comment: The logs are not conclusive. The fact that your services seem to fluctuate between 'passing' and 'failing' could indicate a resource bottleneck. Interesting would also be to see the catalog log with DEBUG level logs.

Comment: @FrankLegler Thanks for your kind response..where can i find Debug level logs???

Comment: You can change the log level for the different Vora services in the Vora Manager UI.

Comment: @FrankLegler I tried in debug mode i got foll logs: 07:58:07 INFO CatalogFactory: returning a Vora catalog client of this Vora catalog server: hdclus01-host1:37866 17/07/31 07:58:07 WARN VoraCatalogClient: Reconnecting (current handle: 2)... 17/07/31 07:58:07 WARN VoraCatalogClient: Reconnecting done (new handle: 7) 17/07/31 07:58:37 ERROR SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Error executing query, currentState RUNNING, java.lang.RuntimeException: could not add table VORATEST to catalog at com.sap.spark.vora.client.VoraClient$$anonfun$createTable$2.‌​applyOrElse(VoraClie‌​nt.scala:381)

Answer (score 0):

If the services are fluctuating then its definitely not stable. Which version of 1.3 you are using? As you are using one node make sure that you have master and worker services are installed and running. This you can see from your cluster manager. The info from logs is not informative enough to nail down the issue.

Comment: If you can for Vora 1.4, it would be better as it is much stable than 1.3. To get debug level logs, go to Vora manager UI -> services -> select catalog service -> In configuration tab you would see many parameters to set and there should be parameter called "log Level", set to debug. Then save and restart the service. Hope this helps!